# Path variable reset problem in XP

Tags: path

after restarting my machine The path variable has been reset.
In what scenarios the path variable is reset?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you set it.

If you run `set PATH=...` in Command Prompt, the environment variable is modified *only* for the `cmd.exe` process (and for all programs you run from the same Command Prompt window). Other processes are not affected.

To make your changes permanent, go to *System Properties → Advanced → Environment Variables* and under *User variables* click *New*.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way to permanently edit the PATH in windows from the command line:

```
C:\WINDOWS>setx PATH "PATH;C:\some_new_path"
```

This will update the PATH by appending the new path to the existing path value. Typing the following command will print the new PATH in all future CMD windows; NOT in the current CMD window:

```
C:\WINDOWS>PATH
```

Typing the following will give you a list of all the environment variables:

```
C:\WINDOWS>set
```